# jQuery parsing XML: get an element with a specific attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, xml-parsing

I'm developing an HTML5 application.

I want to parse an XML like this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <cards>
        ...
        <card id="3">
          <name lang="es"></name>
          <description lang="es"></description>
          <name lang="en"></name>
          <description lang="en"></description>
        </card>
        ...
    </cards>
```

I want to get the name and description that have attribute lang="en".

I start writing code, but I don't know how to finish it:

```
function loadCards(lang)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'data/english.xml',
        dataType: "xml",
        success:parseCardsXml
    });
}

function parseCardsXml(xml)
{
    $(xml).find('Card').each(function()
    {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var name = $(this).find('name');
    }
}
```

By the way, `loadCards` function has an argument (or parameter) called `lang`.

How can I pass this argument to `function parserCardsXml(xml)`?
How can I get name and description with a specific attribute?

Comment: Use the attribute selector:  http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To answer the specific questions, "How can I pass this argument to function parserCardsXml(xml)?"

```
function loadCards(lang)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'data/english.xml',
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function (xml) { parseCardsXml(xml, lang); }
    });
}
```

And, "How can I get name and description with a specific attribute?"

```
function parseCardsXml(xml, lang)
{
    var $xml = $(xml),
        name = $xml.find('name[lang="' + lang + '"]').text(),
        desc = $xml.find('desc[lang="' + lang + '"]').text();
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
var xml='<cards>\
        <card id="3">\
          <name lang="es"></name>\
          <description lang="es"></description>\
          <name lang="en"></name>\
          <description lang="en"></description>\
        </card></cards>';
```

and the jquery part

```
$(xml).find('Card').each(function(i,j)
    {           
       console.log($(j).attr("id"));
       console.log($(j).find("name").attr("lang"));

    });
```

http://www.jsfiddle.net/VZjmV/6/

Answer (score 5):

`$(xml).find('name[lang="en"], description[lang="en"]')` should do the trick

Edit: More complete answer

```
$(xml).find('card').each(function () {
  var id, name, description;
  id          = $(this).attr('id'); // or just `this.id`
  name        = $(this).children('name[lang="en"]').text();
  description = $(this).children('description[lang="en"]').text();
  // do something with the id, name, and description
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but, how can I set var name and var description with values found?